# Run a "non" click function within another function only once

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I run a function only once? I read about jquery .one but it seems to only work with click functions. I need my audio play function to activate only once otherwise I have two audio players when the user clicks on the same link again.

How would I do this? Here is piece of code I need running once:

```
        $(function() {
            $('audio').audioPlayer();
        });
```

and here the full code:

```
$('ul li:nth-child(2)').click(function(e) {;
    e.preventDefault();
    link1.reverse()
    link2.reverse()
    link3.reverse()

    $('#div').uncomment( /* recurse */ true);
    setTimeout(function() {
        link4.play()
        $(function() {
            $('audio').audioPlayer();
        });
        picturefill({
            reevaluate: true
        });
    },
```

Comment: Just move the exact code you specified outside of the `click` handler function.

Comment: It needs to be in the click handler for a specific reason.

Comment: but you have it inside a `document.ready` (thats what `$(function(){...})` is!) within a click function. What are you actually trying to do?

Comment: I have html5 audio players and this audioPlayer script adds additional features for the standard player interface. If I call it with this function then the user interface  updates but only if the user clicks on that link. (One page site). Also additional javascript and resources will be downloaded then. Everything within the click function should run as it is but the player function only once. So all clicks after the first once will literally deactivate it

Comment: Is [this the right plugin you're using](http://tympanus.net/codrops/2012/12/04/responsive-touch-friendly-audio-player/)? Do you want to tell if its playing?

Comment: @Jamiec my plugin is http://osvaldas.info/audio-player-responsive-and-touch-friendly

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could simply use a variable to track whether or not it has been executed. And you don't need the $(function() {...} inside the setTimeout function as this binding is already going to be created after the DOM is ready.

E.g.

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>test</li>
    <li>click me</li>
    <li>test</li>
</ul>
```

JS:

```
var hasPlayed = false;

$(function () {

    $('ul li:nth-child(2)').click(function (e) {;
        e.preventDefault();
        link1.reverse();
        link2.reverse();
        link3.reverse();

        $('#div').uncomment( /* recurse */ true);
        if (!hasPlayed) {
            hasPlayed = true;
            setTimeout(function () {
                link4.play();
                $('audio').audioPlayer();
                picturefill({
                    reevaluate: true
                });
            }, 1000);
        }
    });
});
```

Fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/BenjaminRay/2eaf28jh/

Comment: can it still be in my click handler?

Comment: It wont work, I tried it. Well it runs too but it i the same as not adding it. Second click calls it again

Comment: Try the updated example. Note the revised placement of var hasPlayed = false; and the removal of the $(function() { ... } inside the setTimeout function.

Comment: I understand the boolean false, the variable but how does this play together? How does the browser understand that you mean the actual function being played

Comment: Updated the example and added a fiddle (with the plugin-specific stuff commented out).  All I'm doing is telling the browser not to execute the code that starts the player when hasPlayed is false (!hasPlayed).

Comment: I didnt downvote. Wondering myself why everyone has been downvoted

Answer (score -2):

Try using data attributes,

```js
var playAudio = function() {
       if ($('.audio').data('once') != true) {
          $('.audio').append('Once'); // replace with $('audio').audioPlayer();
          $('.audio').data('once', true)
       }
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="audio"></div>

<a href="" onClick="playAudio(); return false;">Click Me</a>
```

Comment: That could be a solution. Ill try this out now

Answer (score -3):

You could use a guard condition.  I'm not that familiar with this `audioPlayer()`, but if there is a way to ask "is it playing" you could do

```
if (!audioPlayer.isPlaying()) {
  $('audio').audioPlayer();
}
```

Otherwise you could do something like

```
//Outside the click handler
var isFirstRun = true;
...

//Inside the click handler
if (isFirstRun) {
  isFirstRun = false;
  $('audio').audioPlayer();
}
```